# addition flash actionscript 2.0

Tags: actionscript-2, addition

I have a dynamic text with a variable name and instance name of "total". I need it to display the  total price of every button clicked.

I have this code in the button:

```
var vaseprice = 400;
total = price + vaseprice;
```

price is a variable on the frame. My problem is that it doesn't display the total price. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

try putting `_root.total = _root.price + _root.vaseprice` and see if that works

Comment: where are the variables declared? do you have them declared on the timeline as well as in the instance name of the dynamic text?

Comment: there's a variable name in the dynamic text field. make sure it's filled for the total field as 'total'